# Python: NameError: name 'math' is not defined

Tags: python, nameerror

I am new to Python and am using Python3.7 and just started with SpaceInvaders to get me into it.

I just finished creating my player-turtle and enemy-turtle + bullet. Now I am struggeling with the function of the collission of my bullet with the enemy.
When I run the code below, it says:

**NameError: name 'math' is not defined**

```
def isCollision(t1, t2):
    distance = math.sqrt(math.pow(t1.xcor()-t2.xcor(),2)+math.pow(t1.ycor()-t2.ycor(),2))
    if distance < 15:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Can someone please help me with this? :(

Comment: Add 'import math' to the top of your script

Comment: Thank you so much!!!! :D

Answer (score 1):

You are getting error because you haven't imported the **math** library

```
>>> math.pow(2, 10)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'math' is not defined
>>> import math
>>> math.pow(2, 10)
1024.0
>>>
```

Comment: thx for the hlp :)